# apache 'redirect.error404'

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm noticing a bunch of 'domain.com/redirect.error404' entries in my domain's error log. Is this the filename that apache puts on if an ErrorDocument 404 entry exists in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've gotten to views/responses, I'm going to have to say that's exactly what it does. I just reproduced it.